# how to get UTF8 characters from Mysql to store into PDF in a C# prog by Using Itextsharp?

Tags: c#, mysql, pdf, utf-8, itext

I am havig Mysql database with UTF8 encoding my records I am able to see in PHP MyAdmin
properly.
I am also able to generate o/p on google crome with this database and c# prog.
I am using Itextsharp dll to generate pdf.
I want to store data from my database to pdf in devnagri.
I tried setting font as I found many tutorials for that.
setting font worked for hard coded string but not for database.

```
 public Example1()
        {
            string appRootDir = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName;
            try
            {
                // Step 1: Creating System.IO.FileStream object
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(appRootDir + "/PDFs/" + "Chapter1_Example1.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                // Step 2: Creating iTextSharp.text.Document object
                using (Document doc = new Document())
                // Step 3: Creating iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter object
                // It helps to write the Document to the Specified FileStream
                using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs))
                {
                    // Step 4: Openning the Document
                    doc.Open();


                    MySqlDataReader reader = null;
                    string connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost; Database=Records; User ID=root; Password=''";
                    using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection cs = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        string sqlText = "Select * from app";
                        cs.Open();

                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlText, cs);
                       // var font = FontFactory.GetFont(BaseFont.)
                        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\cprkshn.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

                        //Create a specific font object
                        Font f = new Font(bf, 12, Font.NORMAL);

                        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        while (reader.Read())                        
                        {
                            //String s = reader["name"].ToString();

                            doc.Add(new Paragraph(reader["id"] + "---" + reader["name"].ToString() + "¶ããñ‡ãŠÀãè", f));
                        }
                    }

                    // Step 5: Adding a paragraph
                    // NOTE: When we want to insert text, then we've to do it through creating paragraph


                    // Step 6: Closing the Document
                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
            // Catching iTextSharp.text.DocumentException if any
            catch (DocumentException de)
            {
                throw de;
            }
            // Catching System.IO.IOException if any
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                throw ioe;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure your connection - set charset UTF8. You can do it using this MySQL command -

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

Run this command firstly, just after the openning the connection.

Also, you may configure your connection string, try to add `Character Set=utf8`. The result connection string can be like this -

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost; Database=Records; User ID=root; Password=''; Character Set=utf8";
```

Comment: problem is not with mysql I guess coz m able to print it on google chrome. this doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The font you are trying to use doesn't have the Devanagari Unicode range so it won't work. Devanagari characters should use [Unicode U+0900 through U+097F](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0900.pdf) as well as the extension [U+A8E0 through U+A8FF](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UA8E0.pdf). The font you are using has them in the high order ASCII area (128-255). Try switching to ARIALUNI.TTF and you should see your characters appearing.

I know that Arial Unicode is a very large font but try it first just to make sure your code works. Then you can start looking for a smaller font that fits your needs.